# Red Berry Pyracanthaspleas

Tags: hedge

Please can you advise a suitable Pyracantha with Red Berries to form a hedge which would be under a window height of 4 feet.
Thank You

Comment: Be sure yo want thorns there. I had to remove pyracantha from near a patio because of the thorns.

Answer (score 1):

If the window is only 4 feet from the ground and you want to grow pyracantha there, there's only two good choices - Pyracantha 'Red Dwarf', which gets up to 4 feet tall, info here  https://www.villagenurseries.com/product/httpswhl3-wpengine-comproductpyracantha-x-dwarf-red-dwarf-red-firethorn/ and Pyracantha 'Red Elf'   https://www.monrovia.com/plant-catalog/plants/2030/red-elf-pyracantha/. Both have red berries.

Other red berried varieties reach up to 8/10 feet or more, so trying to keep them in check as a hedge under the window will be very difficult; they will also become very wide from front to back with constant cutting, and you may not get berries because of the constant need to cut it back.